# How do I add decimals in Xamarin Forms Entries using C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

For starters I'm very very new to writing code! :)

**What I have so far**...
So far I've used Xamarin.Forms to create a user interface for a sort of specialized calculator. I'm using a Grid Layout containing: a first column of Labels, a second column of Entries (that I have named in Xaml), and a third column of Steppers (so I can change the entries by typing or using the stepper). These 3 views on each row repeat for several rows with different label text on each row and at the bottom of the Grid Layout I have an Entry for the output.

**The problem**...
Basically, I want to buy a certain product at different weights and prices...among other criteria....and I want to quickly figure out how much money I'll make at a future possible sale price. Simply put... I'm trying to add/subtract/multiply/divide using Xamarin.Forms Entries. I've looked everywhere and can't seem find anyone giving an example of how to do this. I've tried different methods and usually end with an error of not being able to convert the Xamarin.Forms entry to a string...So I'm back to zero. Can I get an example of a Method where I would be able to add/subtract/multiply/divide 2 Xamarin.Forms Entry views together in the C# code behind? This seems very simple to me...what am I missing??? Is there a thread/article/video somewhere that I haven't found that covers this?? And like I said, I'm very new so the answer is probably very simple.

Thanks in advance!

Steven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entries deal with strings, not numeric values, so you need to convert them before doing calculations.

```
var amount = Decimal.Parse(EntryA.Text);
var price = Decimal.Parse(EntryB.Text);

var total = amount * price;

// you can use a format string as an argument to ToString()
// to control the output - ie, how many decimals, commas, etc
LabelTotal.Text = total.ToString();
```

In a real app you will want to validate the input in case the user enters text instead of a value number (the `Parse` method will throw an exception if the input is bad);